# Link 2 in-cell data validation lists

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have 2 in-cell data validation lists in Excel. Both cells contain dropdown arrows pointing to 2 columns of a table. What I would like is for when 1 cell contains a value, the other cell contains the value from the corresponding row in the table, but its own column, *and vice-versa*.
So if I select a value from the dropdown in `cell1` it overwrites `cell2`, if I select a value from the dropdown in `cell2` it overwrites `cell1`

i.e. for a table `GoalTbl` with columns `cl` and `d`; a cell named `cl_val` contains a data validation list pointing to `GoalTbl[cl]`. Another cell called `d_val` points to `GoalTbl[d]`

And so to get a `d_val` based on `cl_val` I use a formula like `=INDEX(GoalTbl[d],MATCH(cl_val,GoalTbl[cl],0))`

Similarly to get a value for `cl_val` based on `d_val`, `=INDEX(GoalTbl[cl],MATCH(d_val,GoalTbl[d],0))`

I can't put these formulae in their respective cells for 2 reasons:

1. Since each formula refers to the other cell, I would get a circular reference
2. If I use the drop-down arrow to select a value, it overwrites the formula in that cell

So can I get this linked functionality by changing the lists that the data validation points to - or with a VBA approach?
I suppose this is a combination of a dynamic default formula for a validation, and an overwriting mechanism for 1 cell based on the other - 2 areas I'm not sure how to tackle simultaneously with formulae.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with formula and validation, but you can definitely do this with VBA. Use the Worksheet_Change event, trigger it when a user changes either of the two cells, and fill the other with either a fomula or the value itself. You might want to turn off the error alert, this way allowing values other than the ones on the dropdown to be entered - e.g. the formula. But then again, this would allow your users to simply put anything in those cells. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the pointer towards `Worksheet_Change`, I have a VBA approach;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, [cl_val]) Is Nothing Then
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    UI False
    [d_val] = .Index([Goaltbl[d]], .Match([cl_val], [Goaltbl[cl]], 0))
    UI True
    End With
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, [d_val]) Is Nothing Then
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    UI False
    [cl_val] = .Index([Goaltbl[cl]], .Match([d_val], [Goaltbl[d]], 0))
    UI True
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Where `UI` is simply a Sub* to turn on/off screen updating and events (I have a `Worksheet_Calculate` macro elsewhere which I don't want triggered)

Still, a function approach would be nice to know about - I'm sure something can be done by changing the list input

---

*UI code for reference

```
Public Sub UI(t As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = t
    Application.ScreenUpdating = t
End Sub
```